# c function not returning result

Tags: c, function, return

I've very recently started to learn C, so I realize my question is very basic, but any help would be very much appreciated.

I'm trying to get the function fact to return the res value to main, but when I print out the result in main I just get 0. By inserting some print statements I can see that res is calculating correctly in the fact routine but the result is not returning correctly to main.

I'm sure I'm missing something very basic here.

Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long fact (int n){
    unsigned long res = 1;

    while ( n >= 0 )
    {
        res *= n;
        n--;
    }

    return res;
}

int main (void){
    int n;
    unsigned long res;

    printf("Insert number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n );

    res = fact (n);

    printf("The factorial number is %lu", res);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What will be the value of `n` during the last iteration of the `while` loop?

Comment: this could be easily found out by debugging

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your loop condition is `n >= 0`, which means that `res` will be multipled by 0 before the function returns. Thus the result will always be 0.

Answer (score 7):

You loop condition is wrong.  The last run of `while (n>=0)` will have `n=0`.  Multiplying `res` by this will reset it to 0.

You can fix this by changing your loop to `while (n > 1)`

For future reference, you could investigate problems like this using a debugger (e.g. GDB or visual studio express).  Or by adding `printf` statements to your code to trace the flow and see how the value of `res` changed through the program.

Comment: +1 But `while (n > 1)` would be even better, as multiplying by 1 is useless.

Comment: Wish I could +1 again for suggesting the use of a debugger. You all know the old adage: *Give a man a fish, you'll feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish, you'll feed him for a lifetime.*